# How can i add watermark text over image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**I am trying to add watermark text over the image. I am able to set Single text to image but i don't know how to repeat watermark text like below Image.**

[image]

**Code block:**

```
    Container(           
    child: ColorFiltered(      
    colorFilter: 
    ColorFilter.matrix(filters[index]),
     child: Stack(children: [
    Image.file(widget.editedImage,
    filterQuality: FilterQuality.high),
         Positioned(        
                top: yPosition,
                left: xPosition,
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
                      setState(() {
                        xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
                        yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;           
                      });          
                    },           
            child: Container(    
                 alignment: Alignment.center,  
                 child: Text(            
                    'Confidential',     
                style: TextStyle(            
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,        
                  fontSize: 20,      
                 color: Colors.grey[600])),
    ),),)                     
    ])),                
    ),             
    ),            
    );
```

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-watermark-over-image-in-flutter-e7353e3cf603

Comment: @yahyaparvar I already try this solution but i want to show text repeated like this.

Comment: make an image which have your watermark text "Confidential" and place it above editedImage.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary i also faced similar situation. my work around was: i used a stack and over the image using GridView i printed text like this. however in my case image size was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to make those 'confidential' watermark text as an image and place it as background using stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution,

```
return Stack(
          children: [
            Material(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      for(var i=0;i<=10;i++)
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50 ,horizontal: 20),
                                  child: Transform.rotate(
                                    angle: -51,
                                    child: Text('CONFIDENTIAL', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey),),
                                  ),
                                )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                elevation: 0,
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text('Welcome', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
```